# Should "kingdom" be capitalized when used alone to refer to a country whose name has the word in it (e.g., the United Kingdom)?

Tags: word-usage, capitalization

For instance, if I mention the United Kingdom early in my paragraph and then I want to refer to it as "the kingdom," should I uppercase "kingdom" in this case?

Comment: *Why* do you want to refer to the UK as "the kingdom"? Almost no-one who actually *lives* here would use that term today (it's evocative of medieval times, fantasy novels, and children's nursery stories). If you *want* those archaic overtones, you should probably capitalise the word to emphasise what you're doing.

Comment: @FumbleFingersThank you for your reply. The UK was just an example; I was asking a general question about any country whose name has the word "Kingdom" in it, such as the Hashemite Kingdom of Jordan for instance.

Comment: I don't suppose English is exactly the "national language" of Jordan, so it's not obvious to me why they'd want to call themselves ***the Hashemite Kingdom of*** Jordan (I'd never heard of it before, so I just had to Google that to see what it referred to anywa). I've no idea what Jordanians might think, but it strikes me as "patronising" to refer to their (uncapitalised) ***country / land / nation*** as a (capitalised) ***Kingdom***.

Comment: (Democracy is a crap system, but it's better than any of the alternatives - such as rule by hereditary royalty, tyrannical despots, faceless bureaucrats, uncontrolled anarchy, etc.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree. Thanks again!

Comment: If you're using it as an abbreviated name for the country, rather than as a descriptive term, then it should be capitalized because it's a name. E.g. you can refer to the US as "the States".

Comment: @Barmar This is exactly what I was wondering about. Thank you so much for your input.